# Reporting tools when using SQL server management

Tags: reporting, sql, sql-server

Here's my context :

We are found of SSRS (SQL server reporting services) with visual studio 2008

But the more we use it, the more we see limitations, and bug, and non-implemented feature, and complexity of debuging. I can't find anything on internet other than SSRS related.

What are my other options to make WEB repports based on SQL server, Repports that would be **quick to build** and **easy to debug** ? Is there any options other than SSRS ? What are these options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Syncfusion Report Platform](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/report) is an option to consider.

1. Based on SQL Server: Yes
2. Web oriented: Yes.
3. Quick to Build: Syncfusion Report Platform uses the same file format (RDL) as SSRS. A Desktop designer is provided for creating reports
4. Easy to Debug: The system is simple end accurate error messages are displayed to be able to troubleshoot problems.

[image: Report With Filters]

[image: Report exported to Excel]

The report platform and more are available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, i was afraid no one would suggest anything, i will take a lot of my time investing your product to see if it fits my needs.

Comment: It dosen't seems to work with stored procedures, that's sad because i really liked your repport builder.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Stored procedures are supported. Did you run into a problem?https://help.syncfusion.com/report-platform/reportdesigner/getting-started

Comment: @AntoinePelletier I believe you have submitted a support ticket and our support team will respond there to provide a solution.

Comment: Problem solved, very good product